# Convert records from SQLite to clickable URL

Tags: android

How do I convert records from my `SQLite` table to clickable link. See code below.

```
ListAdapter list = 
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, myCursor, new String [] {"title","url"}, new int [] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2});
```

I want the output of `R.id.text2` to be a clickable URL.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layout file in View which will shows the URL write next

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

And links will be clickable. You also can make e-mail and etc. links clickable.

Please read this for more info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink

Example:

```
<TextView android:text="http://www.google.com" android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:linksClickable="true" android:autoLink="web"></TextView>
```

Good Luck!